# InertiaJS con Vue2 en Laravel - Failed to resolve import "fsevents" - require() vs import()

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-9, vite, inertia.js

Estoy intentando crear un proyecto para trabajarlo con Vue2 (requerimiento forzoso del cliente) e InertiaJS dentro de Laravel 9.

Creé un nuevo proyecto de Laravel 9, seguí todos los pasos de la documentación de InertiaJS para usar Vue2

La documentación de InertiaJS me dice que mi `app.js` debe tener lo siguiente:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    Vue.use(plugin)

    new Vue({
      render: h => h(App, props),
    }).$mount(el)
  },
})
```

Y para habilitar los `dynamic imports` debo instalar:

```
npm install @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

Así como crear un archivo `.babelrc` en la raíz:

```
{
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

Para cambiar la siguiente línea en `app.js`:

```
resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
```

Hecho todo eso, según la documentación de Inertia, tengo el error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://0.0.0.0:5173/resources/js/Pages/
```

Traté de agregar la extensión `.vue` en `app.js`:

```
resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
```

Y tuve el error: `[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.`

En donde me pide instalar `@vitejs/plugin-vue` pero con la salida de Vue3, el plugin de Vue2 se actualizó a `@vitejs/plugin-vue2` por lo que instaló ese, porque el original da error al instalar.

Una vez instalado, modifiqué `app.js` importando `vue` y añadiéndolo a `plugins`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2'

InertiaProgress.init()
createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => import(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        Vue.use(plugin)

        new Vue({
            render: h => h(App, props),
        }).$mount(el)
    },
    plugins: [
        vue()
    ]
})
```

Y ahora me da el error:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "fsevents" from "node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-3DGKH2LC.js?v=40ccd512". Does the file exist?
```

Y este último error ya no encontré nada que me sirviera.

La instalación de Laravel es nueva, creé un componente simple de Vue para validar todo, pero esta configuración inicial es la que está fallando, así que puedo intentar más cosas dado que el proyecto no tiene prácticamente nada.

Comment: Hola! En la página https://bootcamp.laravel.com se indica que **no se debe hacer mezcla de Vue e inertia** Dice un renglón antes de terminar la página: "At any point you may view the code for either framework to see what life is like ***on the other side, just be sure not to mix the code in your project."***

Comment: No puedo ofrecerte recomendaciones porque justamente ahora estoy documentandome sobre ese tema. Pues siempre he preferido usar JS vanilla